# How do I copy contents of a bucket which is of the form bucketName/folder1/folder2

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to copy folder2 contents and not the whole contents of bucketName. I am using the following code but no success. I actually see no output. If I just copy the contents of the bucket and not the sub folders, I see the entire contents in the destination bucket. How do I just copy the contents of the subfolder2 under the bucket.

```
 System.out.println("Listing objects and copying objects");
        if (!prefix.endsWith(delimiter)) {
            prefix += delimiter;
        }
        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName(bucketName)
            .withPrefix(prefix)
            .withDelimiter(delimiter);
        ObjectListing objectListing;            
            objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : 
                objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) { s3Client.copyObject(bucketName, objectSummary.getKey(), bucketName2,  "output/" + objectSummary.getKey());
                System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                        "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + 
                        ")");
            listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
```

Comment: Be more specific about what the problem is. Just telling us that it doesn't work means we have to wildly guess as to what the problem could possibly be. It doesn't compile? What does the compiler tell you? Or does it compile but encounters an exception? What is the exception? Where? Or does it run but the output was not what you expected it to be? What did you expect it to be? Please take some time to add details to your question so that we can most effectively help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up something to try this out with you. I created two buckets, one called mytestbucket20141006, which acts as the source, and another one called mytestbucket20141006b, acts as destination. Inside the source bucket, I have a folder called afolder, which contains couple files.

The following code successfully copied objects to the destination:

```
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName("mytestbucket20141006")
        .withPrefix("afolder/afolder2/afolder3");
        //.withDelimiter("/");
    ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
        String key = objectSummary.getKey();
        String newKey = key.replace("afolder/afolder2/afolder3/", "afolder3/");
        s3.copyObject("mytestbucket20141006", key, "mytestbucket20141006b",  newKey);
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```

Comment: Considering afolder as my folder, I have 2 other folders in this say mytestbucket20141006/afolder/afolder2/afolder3. I want to copy only contents of afolder3 into my new bucket. I am unable to do this. However, I can just copy all the contents of a bucket to new bucket. I followed the same code as yours and it worke3d. Now I want only afolder3 contents to be copied.

Comment: When I copy, I have afolder/afolder2/afolder3 in my destination bucket. I just want newBucket/afolder3. IS it possible. Thanks.